# Mathematical notation of mutually exclusive events

Tags: probability, notation

Which is the formal mathematical notation that the following sentence can be stated?

"Let the mutually exclusive events $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$"

Comment: What do you want this for? If you're writing something, "The events $A_1,\,A_2,\,\ldots,A_n$ are (pairwise) mutually exclusive" is likely clearer than any symbolic expression of the same.

Comment: @MiloBrandt I was reading something and I was curious about it because I have never come across it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to write it is:

$\forall i, j: 1 \le i \lt j \le n \implies A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$

(Although it seems a lot easier to understand the way you stated it!)

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what you want to express, do you want to describe that the events are mutually intersection free, then write it as Dan Brumleve suggests as
$$
\forall i, j: 1 \le i \lt j \le n \implies A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset
$$
if you want to express that the sets (events) are indeed mutually independent to some probability measure, then you might be better off with
$$\forall i, j: A_i \perp_{i\neq j} A_j$$
Keep in mind, that both statements are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen things like
$$A_1\sqcup\dotsb\sqcup A_n$$
before. I can't say that this is universal or widely accepted though.